# Do we have to handle the MTU in Bluetooth LE communications at the Application level?

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I’m building a Bluetooth Low Energy test app in C# to make two Windows 10 apps communicate (the **central** one using a commercial .NET Framework SDK, the **peripheral** one using UWP) and I’m trying to wrap my head around the impacts of the MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) at the ***Application*** level. Here’s my comprehension so far:

In the **L2CAP** layer of the Bluetooth stack, there is some fragmentation and recombination going on for “large” packets. So if data exceeds the MTU, it will be sent in chunks. 
In UWP, we use the `GattLocalCharacteristic.WriteRequested` callback to handle the received data. In the sample I’m working on, when sending 2-3K of data, it is called for every chunk of 522 bytes (probably the negotiated MTU?), so it seems I must handle the recombination at the application level, although it’s supposed to be done at L2CAP level (if I understand correctly). This implies I have to detect when the data is complete (using some sort of length field, “EOF”, or whatever mechanism) which adds some burden to the protocol and feels very low-level to me. I would have thought the `WriteRequested` event would have fired only once with all the data in it.

On top of that, the UWP SDK (`Windows.Devices.Bluetooth` namespace ) doesn’t seem to provide a way of knowing the actual MTU (something like `requestMtu` on Android), so here again I would have to craft some custom plumbing.

So I guess the question is: do I have to detect the negotiated MTU (how in UWP?) and fragment and recombine the packets myself?

Comment: In windows serial devices uses timers to pass data to/from events.  So with any serial communication device you must know when the end of message occurs to work reliably.  Serial Device get data in chunks and the chunk that gets transmitted may not be exactly as the one received.

Comment: As far as I remember you can only GET max PDU size in WinRT. In Classic Bluetooth you can change (read and write) MTU size.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to negotiate MTU on windows 10.

It only depends on the Bluetooth version used.
The maximum MTU for for BLE4.0/4.1 is 23 bytes and for BLE4.2 251 bytes.
For other versions on windows 10 I don't know the maximum.
The MTU is defined by the L2CAP and can be anywhere between 23 and infinity. The implementation of the Bluetooth stack is the key factor of determining the  MTU on both client and peripheral.
Windows 10 devices will always try to negotiate the maximum MTU.

Comment: OK so it looks like the SDK on the central side encapsulates the fragmentation/recombination correctly, meaning I can write data that exceeds the MTU just once and it is sent in packets (how many, which size, I don't care), but on the peripheral end (UWP) the event will pop X times instead of only once, so it is not as well encapsulated and it forces me to recombine packets by myself. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: No that is not guaranteed. Receive buffers can overflow and that way you can loose data. It depends on the SDK and the Bluetooth stack. Even if Bluetooth version 5 or higher is used on both sides it's safer to stick with packets of 248 bytes.
If you wait GattCommunicationStatus.Success before sending the next packet you can try larger packets until truncation of data  occurs or until processing of the data takes too long and the receive buffer is not emptied fast enough.

Comment: Is it safe to say that on UWP the MTU is not supported at the right level? Because with the other API on the central, this is totally transparent. It should not be transparent on one side (thus not requiring packet segmentation) and not be supported on the other, right?

Comment: Windows documentation lacks a lot of information about Bluetooth, especially BLE. Here I found a lot of info:  https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-5-speed-maximum-throughput/
It's related to the nRF52 Platform, but very useful.

Answer (score 1):

ATT packets can span multiple LL packets. The size of the data unit within an ATT packet is known as the Maximum Transmission Unit (MTU). The default size is 23 bytes (which allows the packet to fit in one LL packet) but the size can be negotiated via the Exchange MTU Request & Response.

Per the Bluetooth Core Specification, the maximum allowed length of an attribute value (the ATT payload) is 512 bytes3. While this technically means the MTU size can be slightly larger than 512 bytes (to accomodate for the ATT protocol overhead), most bluetooth stacks support a maximum MTU value of 512 bytes